# TypeError: Column 'year_2021' has dtype object, cannot use method 'nlargest' with this dtype

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Python dataframe that looks like:

```
    year_2021   year_2020   year_2019   year_2018   year_2017   year_2016   year_2015
A   15.930541127542696  0.12659425148389353 37.859222886444584  0.7502044402344105  29.867551207184103  -2.62377211249297   -0.20709969350376067
AA  67.78493901734711   0.8676822974374843  7.609706605792995   -0.4184107467700045 -18.02591304685353  -1.2791578388405083 -51.821640736128046
AAL 61.46728433834196   -4.05834067688741   -45.78892961483622  1.4295670957092637  -11.699505205100467 1.1522856582117076  -39.40366183570082
```

and I am trying to get the largest n per year:

```
dataframe = yearly_returns.nlargest(5, "year_"+str(2021))
```

which gives me the error `TypeError: Column 'year_2021' has dtype object, cannot use method 'nlargest' with this dtype`

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to ensure the columns are in float format by `astype(float)` before using `nlargest()`, as follows:

```
dataframe = yearly_returns.astype(float).nlargest(5, "year_"+str(2021))
```

If you need only the data from the concerned column, instead of all columns from the whole dataframe, you should consider using [`Series.nlargest()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.nlargest.html) instead of [`DataFrame.nlargest()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html), as follows:

```
series = yearly_returns["year_"+str(2021)].astype(float).nlargest(5)
```

The result will be a series of the concerned column instead of the whole dataframe with data from irrelevant years.

Answer (score 0):

Object type cannot have nlargest. so try converting to int or float

```
dataframe = yearly_returns.astype('float').nlargest(5, "year_"+str(2021))
```

or

```
dataframe = yearly_returns.astype('int').nlargest(5, "year_"+str(2021))
```